How do you handle game performance issues?
I’ve been running into some game performance issues lately and could really use some advice. How do you handle game performance issues? I’m talking about things like lag, slow loading times, and frame rate drops. Do you have any tips or strategies that have worked for you?

This is a little like coming to your doctor and saying "how do you handle illnesses?" — there's not just one answer. They've had to study for years to learn the various patterns of symptoms and recommended treatments, and they won't be able to condense all that into a concise response. You'll get much more useful and actionable advice if you ask a narrower question, specific to one particular performance problem in your game: the same way you'd go to your doctor with a specific symptom to investigate. You can always ask another question later about the next problem after that.

Start profiling,
Take a timestamp at the start of each frame and put it in a ring buffer, then render the differences between frames as a graph. That will show you how consistent each frame is.
At the start and exit of each function take a timestamp with the name of the function, add to another (larger) ring buffer, keep track per frame when it starts in that buffer. Add the ability to save a copy to investigate the data without it getting overridden. Then you can dive into the slow frames and see what part of the game is slowing it down.
To fix slow loading times, reduce the amount of work required to load the assets, Find a format that is easy to unpack.
Profiling doesn't let you fix the death of a thousand cuts type of issue, that just requires experience to know for example that the OOP-style abstract entity object with a virtual update() is worse than having separate sets for each type of object and doing the bulk update per type. (the latter has better opportunities for vectorising which is free performance if you can squeeze it out)
